# An idea to teach equation except balance model

Tags: algebra-precalculus, education, motivation

I looking for an idea to start teaching the equation of algebra, but not use the balance model. I am looking for a new motivational idea or a pedagogical method to start teaching equations.

The link below contains a good context for a balance model, But I am looking for something different.   https://www.geogebra.org/m/xrwqt4ty

If you use some other idea's please give a hint. If you use a motivational picture on this subject, please share it if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to be clear, you're teaching algebraic equations to a group of I presume middle-school/junior-high students as their first exposure? I feel that might be relevant. Not that I have much else to say, but I do wonder if this might be more relevant on the math education SE (https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions).

Comment: Maybe start with identities like $1m=100cm$ or $1 USD=0.9Euro$ and then move to proportions like $5m=x cm$ or $1.5USD=x Euros$. Later you can introduce various formulas like $C^\circ=\frac59(F^\circ-32^\circ)$. Then you can conclude that the root of equation is a number that turns the equation into an identity.

Comment: @farruhota: Your comment was impressive and very useful to me. +1